# divide my projects in github into categories

Tags: github, github-for-windows

How can I divide my projects in github into categories such that web projects in web category, java projects into java file and so on?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this is not (yet?) supported.

Your repository page lists all projects, and the local GitHub client "GitHub for Windows" (actually [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)) does the same.
[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is just a Git client, with no notion of "project category"